# Does verifying OAuth2 `access_token` validity count towards API call quota?

Tags: support, oauth2, api-v2.2

Does this Stack Exchange API endpoint count towards quota usage? :

> http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-access-tokens

(This is the  most promising API call I found for verifying the validity of an `access_token`.)

I'm doing user authentication, not Stack Exchange API calls.
My application's cache acts as the first level for checking whether a user is still logged in, but when a call slips through, it has to hit some API call on Stack Exchange API to verify whether the token is still valid.

---

Which gets me to my second question:
Is there a purpose-built endpoint just for verifying the validity of an `access_token`?
GitHub apparently has:

> [#check-an-authorization](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#check-an-authorization) (*"OAuth applications can use a special API method for checking OAuth token validity without running afoul of normal rate limits for failed login attempts"*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, calls to  `/access-tokens/{accessTokens}` use API quota.  You can see that by repeatedly running [/2.2/access-tokens/XBWL0stf*YIOCl7WpJHqYA))](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/access-tokens/XBWL0stf*YIOCl7WpJHqYA%29%29) for example.
With each call, the `quota_remaining` value will decrease.

**However**, there is no reason that the token check has to use the same `key` as your main app.  The token check and your main app would then use separate 10K quotas.  (You can see this in action by comparing the different quota values between, say, [this page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-access-tokens) and [this page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox).)

---

As for checking if an access_token is valid, merely use the `/access-tokens/{accessTokens}` route.

If the `access_token` **is valid**, that route returns a response like this (default filter):

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "scope": [
        "read_inbox"
      ],
      "account_id": 131474,
      "expires_on_date": 1415948311,
      "access_token": "XBWL0stf*YIOCl7WpJHqYA))"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9956
}
```

If the `access_token` is **invalid or expired**, that route returns a response like this (default filter):

```
{
  "items": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9946
}
```

---

If you pass more than 1 token to `/access-tokens/{accessTokens}`, only the valid ones will be in the `items` array of the response.